# Redshift - raiseerror when no rows found?

Tags: amazon-redshift, raiserror

I'm trying to achieve the following in redshift -> check if a query returns any records, if yes then run another query and pull back results, if not raise an error and fail the main query. This is how it would work in sql server:

```
 IF exists (SELECT * from [TABLE] where COLUMN1 = 'ABC')
    SELECT [COLUMN2] from [TABLE] where COLUMN1 = 'ABC'
       ELSE  RAISERROR ('Error',16, 1);
```

I've failed miserably with using the redshfit CASE function and it seems that raiserror doesn't exist?

Any ideas?

Comment: Redshift SQL doesn't include many of the procedural programming elements that are in T-SQL (SQL Server), such as IF..THEN constructs. This kind of logic typically needs to be handled by an external application.

Answer (score 0):

If using psql to execute the script, try a divide by zero error to conditionally abort the script if no rows found:

\set ON_ERROR_STOP ON

select 1/count(*) from [TABLE] where column1 = 'ABC' 
....
....